# Upgrading to a brushless motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I have a mini-lathe with a 500W 3/4 HP variable speed motor, that is run by a controller at two different gearings. However, even at the LOW gearing I find the torque to be a little inadequate.

Is it possible to upgrade this motor to brushless and get more torque/HP?

[image: MM7x14 motor]

Comment: You will need more watts in the motor, (1HP$\approx$750W) which means more current which the windings may not be able to handle.

Comment: You need to be careful because the rest of the machine may not be designed to handle the amount of torque produced by the upgraded motor.

Comment: I don't think they are interchangeable. Maybe try using a different sized pulleys?